# Jupyterlab: plots don't fit in jupyter cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

This just started happening for some reason...

I know there are some similar posts about this, and they all say, "just use Jupyter Lab!", however, my problem is in Jupyter Lab.

When I plot with pyplot, the cell size doesn't increase to fit the plot:

[image]

- I just did `conda update jupyter lab`
- `%matplotlib inline` is the first line in my notebook

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you scroll down?

Comment: yes...I can.. :)

Comment: I believe you can click the left side of the plot to change the behavior. Well, actually, that is the left side of the output cell.

Comment: @Sraw, I swear, this doesn't work for me. I click and get no functioning!

Comment: Hum, maybe you can right click and choose "Disable Scrolling for Outputs"? I mean you can click that blue part in your picture.

Comment: The blue part will collapse it down to triple dots...I'll try "Disable Scrolling for Outputs" and see what happens! Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Well, you need to right-click the blue part.